# How to use Git to maintain several versions of my code?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

I am maintaining an application and I want to have multiple versions of it, say an **international version** and a **Chinese version**. Of course, the configuration files for different versions are different, but there will be some code-level version control needed, and here is what I mean.

Let's consider a simple file structure of the project with only two files:

```
.
├── auth.py
├── otherthings.py
```

And let's say the `otherthings.py` is the same for both **international version** and **Chinese version**, but the `auth.py` file is different. So my question is, what is the best practice to use Git to do proper version control for both versions in this same repository?

Ideally, I would like to somehow configure two branches, when merging with each other, it only pickup the otherthings.py but ignore auth.py but how to do this?

Another way I can think about is to maintain a **master branch**, and maintain everything of `otherfiles.py` in it and merge to the **Chinese branch** and **international branch**. This sounds right in theory but will import many complications in implementation, as it will be hard for the two branches to merge back to master, which is something that seems will happen a lot in real development (we probably will find a bug or something needs to be changed when in two of the branches).

So how is there a better way to deal with this issue? Thank you very much.

P.S. I do know I can solve this issue by just putting app settings in configuration files and running different confs. But there are some use cases that using configuration files that will include many complications. For example, authentication in China is very different as they don't use Facebook or Google, and the login module, both frontend, and backend, even database is a complete rewrite. That means if you keep this logic in the configuration file, there will be a lot of `if` `else` other than the main logic to just deal with region difference. Doing this in version control will possibly make things cleaner.

Comment: to b ehonest this sounds like you have a design issue if the implementation is this language specific. Can you give a concrete example as to why you need to handle two languages differently, and why they can't just be on two separate modules or functions rather than branches?

Comment: @joshmeranda It's not about language. Language can be easily handled with conf files and i18n. I am talking about, for example, in China, the social login will have to use different services other than FB and Google which is used in the rest of the world. In this case, both the backend and frontend, even the database will need to be redesigned accordingly, using a conf file for that is going to include a lot of complications. It will be cleaner if we can do this in version control.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense (might be beneficial to clarify your question with those points). I would still stay is probably better to have a package called `auth` which then implements the different type of authentication, etc that you may need, and add a check to determine which one is necessary for the user's location. Something to the effect of `if location.isChina(): auth.chineseAuth() else: auth.internationalAuth()`

Comment: @joshmeranda Yeah, certainly, I am also thinking of this strategy but then the logic will be maintained in the code which brings unnecessary complications. Especially the frontend will be a complete rewrite (they do authentication with QR code or externally call Wechat directly). Adding multiple 'ifs' across the code will make the code less readable and less clean, import potential bugs, or, at least I have to re-structure the code to make it cleaner. That's why I think there might be a better option, to just allow two versions of the same file exist in two different branches.

Comment: I'd argue that would be even less readable and maintainable. What happens when some common functionality or business logic changes? You'll have to change the same code in two separate code bases, add the same new tests to both making the likelihood of bugs even higher (especially if you change one but forget the other) and as you expand or begin to support more authentication methods this will just be exacerbated. It would be a lot easier to have the multiple conditionals (maybe wrapped in some utility) and serve whatever front-end component works for that authentication method.

Comment: @joshmeranda Yeah agreed, from people's replies there seem to have no other options.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is do not use Git for that. If you have multiple branches, you really have several separate and independent copies of your program. Even though Git gives you some powerful tools for maintaining them, you will still have a lot of extra work (and therefore problems) to keep them synchronized.

Instead, work on one Git branch and write your code in a manner that can adapt to different languages dynamically and work with multiple configurations at once. You can use a library such as https://pypi.org/project/python-i18n/.

Comment: than you! As I said in the question, there are configuration files to handle many of these issues already and in fact, I am using i18n. But this is higher than that, as there will be modules that are completely different in two versions, and all of these modules need long-term maintenance and hence the problem occurs.